# Utilisation de « sinon » et « si non »

Tags: orthographe, conjonctions, négation

Considérons une séquence de deux questions qui aurait cette forme :

> Est-ce que […] ? Si non, […] ?

Est-ce là une utilisation correcte de « si non » (par opposition à « si oui ») ? Avec l'écriture « Sinon, … », ne peut-on pas comprendre le mot comme une vulgaire transition ?

Quels sont les différents points de vue à ce sujet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je crois qu'est apparue [sur le blog « À la fortune du mot »](http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/archive/2012/06/01/en-un-mot-sinon-rien.html) une bonne synthèse de l'ensemble des réponses à cette question.

En résumé :

- Il y a ceux qui considèrent que *sinon* s'écrit toujours en un seul mot ou qui le suggèrent en ne mentionnant pas de statut spécial pour *si non* en deux mots. (Thomas, Girodet, Grevisse)
- Ceux qui acceptent *si non* comme une ellipse à « *si la réponse est non* », mais qui considèrent que *sinon* est l'unique orthographe lorsque ce mot signifie « autrement », « sans quoi », « si ce n'est », lorsqu'il évoque une alternative ou lorsqu'il complémente une hypothèse introduite par « *si* ». (Larousse, Hanse, Joseph, l'OQLF)
- Il y a aussi ceux qui ne se prennent pas la tête, et suggèrent que les deux puissent être synonymes (Robert). Comme l'indique Littré, l'ancienne langue séparait *si* de *non*, donc pourquoi pas ?

Comment: Je serais curieux de faire une recherche là-dessus, mais dans le domaine technique, on fait généralement parti de la deuxième école: "sinon" dans le sens de "else" et "si non" dans le sens de "if not".

Comment: Personnellement je ne vois aucune raison valable, grammaticale ou autre, de considérer *si non* comme faux, dans la plupart des cas.

Answer (score 20):

Le *Dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française* (A. Thomas) dit que « sinon » s'écrit toujours en un seul mot. Littré indique pour « sinon » :

> ÉTYMOLOGIE
>   *Si*, et *non*. L'ancienne langue, comme on a vu, séparait *si* de *non*.

*Le Bon Usage* contraste lui explicitement *si oui* et *sinon*, ce qui achève de répondre : ***si non* en deux mots ne s'emploie pas**. Paragraphe *1154 a.* sur *Sinon* :

> *Si oui* permet de présenter elliptiquement d'une manière affirmative une éventualité exprimée dans le contexte : « s'il en est ainsi ». Pour présenter de façon négative cette éventualité (elle-même positive ou négative), on emploie *sinon*, agglutination de *si non*.

Comment: Tu pourrais ajouter le point de vue du Larousse cité par [Un francophone](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/684/utilisation-de-sinon-et-si-non/687#687) ? Étant donné que le style des deux questions proposées ressemble à celui d'un questionnaire, je pense qu'il faut le citer. (Je ne peux pas accepter les deux réponses, je le ferais sinon.)

Comment: Bon, le délai est maintenant dépassé, j'ai écrit une petite synthèse dans une nouvelle réponse :-)

Answer (score 2):

J'aurais tendance à faire comme toi (et nous ne sommes pas isolé, voir ce qu'en dit [Larousse](http://www.larousse.com/fr/dictionnaires/francais/sinon/72888/difficulte) même s'ils n'ont l'air d'envisager « si non » que dans le cadre d'un questionnaire), mais Grevisse donne

> Sors-tu maintenant ? *Sinon* je partirai sans toi.

sans que j'ai vu un endroit où il traitait de la différence.

Comment: Ben là, le *sinon* me semble plutôt correct! Il ne fait pas forcément référence à la réponse à la question, mais à une condition implicite.

Comment: J'aime beaucoup cet exemple, qui achève tout à fait mes velléités à écrire *si non* en deux mots, tout comme @StéphaneGimenez, pour le différencier d'un *sinon* que j'emploie beaucoup comme quelconque transition (par exemple pour "parlons d'autre chose").

Answer (score 1):

D'un point de vue de la règle, mais même dans le langage de tous les jours (qui est plus permissif pourtant) on emploie toujours *sinon*, et jamais *si non*. Y compris dans le cas d'une question admettant ces deux réponses:

> Viendra-t-il ? Si oui, j'aimerais vraiment le rencontrer. Et sinon, tant pis !

Comment: Ton *sinon* répond au *si* dans cet exemple. Ce n'est pas un bon exemple.

Comment: Salut Stéphane. Ça marcherait dans l'autre sens: "viendra-t-il ? Sinon tant pis, mais si oui, je serai ravi de le rencontrer". Mais j'ai peut-être mal compris ton commentaire en fait, car dans tous les cas oui et non répondent au si, non ?

Comment: C'est un peu moins naturel :-) Dans ce cas la condition implicite est “si il vient”. Bref, je suis quand même d'accord que “sinon” est plus courant. Mais reste que je préfère *si non* pour abréger « si la réponse est non », même si apparemment ça fait pas l'unanimité.

Comment: Je vois ce que tu veux dire, et comme F'x l'explique, on utilise "si non", mais sous sa forme agglomérée "sinon". Hem, tout ça tout ça...

Comment: Aucune règle grammaticale ne peut justifier que *si non* est faux. *Si* + *non*, c'est bien du français grammaticalement correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pour le bon usage de sinon / si non, rien de tel que la compréhension mnémonique des choses !
Article intéressant sur JeRetiens: http://jeretiens.net/du-bon-usage-de-sinon-et-de-si-non/

Answer (score 0):

To me the meaning is different. "Sinon" is exactly "else" / "otherwise", "si non" is exactly "if the answer is 'no', then"